# Could you please update something in a way

Tags: phrases, could

I would like to ask somebody to update something using the phrase "Could you please update something" and I would like to add some explanation on what I expect as a result from that update but I'm not sure how to do that.

I was thinking about the following:

Could you please update something so it will {some explanation}?

does it sound natural?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Could you please update your resume so it will include your most recent experience?" "Could you please update the project plan so it will reflect last month's delays?" These work fine. You can also replace "so it will" with "to" in each of these cases.

Answer (score -1):

Update is fine, but for a bit more formality consider:

**attest to**  [the free dictiionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/attest)

> To confirm that something is true.

As in:

> Please attest to the accuracy of the information in X file.